# Date range query with lucene

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search, date-range

I am trying to take data between specific date ranges from mssql db. But returns nothing. I found a solution here on stackoverflow but it is not working.

Here what I have done :

This is the date field from the entity class:

```
 @Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "tarih")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@DateBridge(resolution = Resolution.MILLISECOND)
private Date tarih;
```

This is how I am trying to take date between specific dates:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal2.setTime(new Date(114, 12, 15, 3, 4,4));


    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));


    TermRangeQuery luceneRangeDateQuery = newStringRange("tarih", DateTools.dateToString(cal2.getTime(), DateTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND),
     DateTools.dateToString(cal.getTime(), DateTools.Resolution.MILLISECOND), true, true);
    org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneRangeDateQuery);


    List<Satislar> kayitliSatislar = fullTextQuery.list();
```

This is db record and it is type is datetime:

[image: This is db record and it is type is datetime:]

This is the output these 2 lines and query sent:

```
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal2.getTime()));
```

[image]

Comment: It all depends a bit which version of Search you are using. Behavior has changed between Search 4 and 5. What's your version? Also, what's the deal with 'cal2' in your example. The construction of it looks odd to me. Is this supposed to be the start range? Where is 'newStringRange' coming from and what does it do?

Comment: I have managed to get it work. I did not add @ Field property to date field. So it was not indexed. But i did not seen an example with that annotation. So it was supposed to work. Dont know. Maybe annotation library has changed. And in @ DateBridge field encoding type should be defined as string. Because default date type is integer and it does not cast.