# How to search in Hibernate Search by date as LocalDateTime?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-8, lucene, hibernate-search

There is:

- Line;
- Score;
- Date.

Search on the line and the store is carried out as follows:

```
@Override
public List<Delivery> searchNewDeliveriesBy(long storeId, String text, Long selectedDateAsMills) {
    try (Session session = createSession()) {
        Store store = session.get(Store.class, storeId);
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(Delivery.class)
                .get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.bool()
                .must(
                        qb.keyword().onFields(DELIVERY_SEARCH_FIELDS).matching(text).createQuery()
                )
                .must(
                        qb.keyword().onField("store").matching(store).createQuery()
                )
                .createQuery();
        //noinspection unchecked
        return Search.getFullTextSession(session)
                .createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Delivery.class)
                .setSort(sortByFieldScore)
                .list();
    }
}
```

My entity (without too much):

```
public class Delivery {
    ...
    private LocalDateTime deliveryDateMin;

    private LocalDateTime deliveryDateMax;
    ...
}
```

I need to add a condition so that the selected time (method variable `selectedDateAsMills`) is between `deliveryDateMin` and `deliveryDateMax`.

There is a class like LocalDateTimeBridge, but there are no examples of use on the Internet. This answer ([How to search between dates (Hibernate Search)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812093/how-to-search-between-dates-hibernate-search)) does not fit because there is `java.util.Date`, not `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

**UPDATE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DELIVERY")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Cacheable
@Indexed
public class Delivery {
    @Column(name = "delivery_date_min")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM")
    @Field
    @FieldBridge(impl = LocalDateTimeBridge.class)
    private LocalDateTime deliveryDateMin;
    @Column(name = "delivery_date_max")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM")
    @Field
    @FieldBridge(impl = LocalDateTimeBridge.class)
    private LocalDateTime deliveryDateMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your number of milliseconds to a localDateTime, then just add add two range queries:

```java
        LocalDateTime selectedDateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli( selectedDateAsMills )
                .atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) // ofEpochMilli assumes the given millis are in the UTC timezone
                .toLocalDateTime();

        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = qb.bool()
                .must(
                        qb.keyword().onFields(DELIVERY_SEARCH_FIELDS).matching(text).createQuery()
                )
                .must(
                        qb.keyword().onField("store").matching(store).createQuery()
                )
                .must(
                        qb.range().onField("deliveryDateMin").below(selectedDateTime).createQuery()
                )
                .must(
                        qb.range().onField("deliveryDateMax").above(selectedDateTime).createQuery()
                )
                .createQuery();
```

If it doesn't work for you, please explain what happens and give more information about your entity (the `@Field` annotations in particular).

Comment: As I understand it, you need to add `@Field @FieldBridge(impl = LocalDateTimeBridge.class)` annotations to an entity. Am I right?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you had these annotations already but left them out of your snippet. Yes you need `@Field`, but you don't need `@FieldBridge(impl = LocalDateTimeBridge.class)`: it will be inferred automatically by Hibernate Search.